# How do I change the hard code user id into the authenticated user?

Tags: php, laravel

In my controller I have the following code

```php
    $assignents =Assign::whereHas('users', function ($q) {
        $q->where('user_id', 3); 
    })->get();
```

I would like to have the number 3 be the authenticated user who is logged in. How can I rewrite this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Auth](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication) facade to [retrieve the authenticated user.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user)

```
$assignents = Assign::whereHas('users', function ($q) {
    $q->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id); 
})->get();
```

Comment: `Auth::user()->id;` or `Auth::id()`

Answer (score 0):

you can do this without Auth Facade

```php
$assignents = Assign::whereHas('users', function ($q) {
    $q->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id); 
})->get();
```

or

```php
$assignents = Assign::whereHas('users', function ($q) {
    $q->where('user_id', auth()->id()); 
})->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get authenticate user id by following ways:

Using `auth()` helper function

```php
auth()->user()->id or auth()->id()
```

Using `Auth` Facade

```php
Auth::user()->id, Auth::id()
```

Or you can get it by `Request`

```php
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $request->user()->id;
}
```